# Renomear uma variável e atualizá-la no restante do projeto

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tem alguma maneira fácil ou automática de atualizar o restante do seu código quando se renomeia uma determinada variável na linha `Dim`?

O que eu tenho:

```
Dim ABC As String
If Range("A2").Value = 1 Then
    ABC = Range("C2") & ".xls"
ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 2 Then
    ABC = Range("C2") & ".xlsx"
ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 3 Then
    ABC = Range("C2") & ".xlsm"
Else
    ABC = Range("C2") & ".txt"
    End If
```

O que eu quero:

```
Dim XYZ As String   'renomear ABC por XYZ
If Range("A2").Value = 1 Then
    XYZ = Range("C2") & ".xls"
ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 2 Then
    XYZ = Range("C2") & ".xlsx"
ElseIf Range("A2").Value = 3 Then
    XYZ = Range("C2") & ".xlsm"
Else
    XYZ = Range("C2") & ".txt"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não há uma função ou ferramenta específica para isso, mas o mais comum é utilizar o famoso "Encontrar/Substituir" (Ctrl + F). Quando estiver com o VBA aberto, clique em `Ctrl`+`F` e em seguida no botão `Substituir`/`Replace` (ou diretamente no atalho `Ctrl`+`H` para a janela de `Substituir`/`Replace`).

Digite o texto antigo, o novo, selecione onde vc quer procurar e substituir o valor (*muito importante*) e aí em `Substituir tudo`/`Replace all`.

[image: Tela para substituir textos]

O ponto negativo, variáveis com menos caracteres arriscam de serem confundidos com caracteres no meio de outras palavras, tipo `ng` (presente em `Range`) ou letras soltas (como `i`, `j`, `x`, `y´...)